# Javascript regex alphanumeric english and japanese

Tags: javascript, regex, alphanumeric, kana

I am trying to make a regex that only allows chars `A-Z` + ints `0 - 9` together with dash - and underscore _ but also Japanese chars.

```
$.validator.addMethod("alphaDash", function(value, element) {
        return this.optional(element) || /^[a-zA-Z0-9-_]+$/i.test(value);
      }, "Username must contain only letters, numbers, dashes or underscores.");
```

The regex above `/^[a-zA-Z0-9-_]+$/` only works for english chars, how can I make it accept japanese chars? Hiragana/Katakana/Kanji

Comment: See [Check whether a string contains Japanese/Chinese characters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43418812/check-whether-a-string-contains-japanese-chinese-characters).

Comment: FWIW, the `XRegExp` lib is pretty darned cool: http://xregexp.com/plugins/#unicode

Comment: Does [`^[\u3040-\u30ff\u3400-\u4dbf\u4e00-\u9fff\uf900-\ufaff\uff66-\uff9fa-zA-Z0-9-_]+$`](https://regex101.com/r/pLoL5S/1) work for you?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Oh yes unix code, that should work!

Comment: Watch out since these are script ranges, they do not match just letters/digits. Perhaps, you really need to use XRegExp and its `\pL` and `\pN` constructs to match any Unicode letter and digit.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I tried the lib with this: ``/[a-zA-Z0-9-_\p{Hiragana}\p{Katakana}]+$/`` but it fails If my string ends with a Hiragana or Katakana char which I dont want

Comment: Could you please share the string you tested against?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew **werえ** will fail, **werえ3** will pass

Comment: [I got *true* in both cases](https://jsfiddle.net/x455p6hq/).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew my code  ``$.validator.addMethod("alphaDash", function(value, element) {
        return this.optional(element) || /[a-zA-Z0-9-_\p{Hiragana}\p{Katakana}]+$/i.test(value);
      }, "Username must contain only letters, numbers, dashes or underscores.");``

Comment: Sorry, you are doing it all wrong. You cannot use Unicode properties like `\p{Han}` (this matches all Chinese chars) with JS native `RegExp`. You must reference the `XRegExp` library.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew got it to work: ``$.validator.addMethod("alphaDash", function(value, element) {
        var re = XRegExp('^[a-zA-Z0-9-_\\p{Hiragana}\\p{Katakana}]+$');
        return this.optional(element) || re.test(value);
      }, "Username must contain only letters, numbers, dashes or underscores.");``

Comment: Yes, but `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` = `\w`. Also, don't you need to match Kanji as well? You only included Hiragana & Katakana.

Comment: I added an answer based on that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Acc. to [XRegExp Unicode scripts](https://github.com/slevithan/xregexp/blob/master/src/addons/unicode-scripts.js):

- Hiragana (`\p{Hiragana}`) char regex: `[\u3041-\u3096\u309D-\u309F]|\uD82C\uDC01|\uD83C\uDE00`
- Katakana (`\p{Katakana}`) char regex: `[\u30A1-\u30FA\u30FD-\u30FF\u31F0-\u31FF\u32D0-\u32FE\u3300-\u3357\uFF66-\uFF6F\uFF71-\uFF9D]|\uD82C\uDC00`
- Kanji (`\p{Han}`): `[\u2E80-\u2E99\u2E9B-\u2EF3\u2F00-\u2FD5\u3005\u3007\u3021-\u3029\u3038-\u303B\u3400-\u4DB5\u4E00-\u9FD5\uF900-\uFA6D\uFA70-\uFAD9]|[\uD840-\uD868\uD86A-\uD86C\uD86F-\uD872][\uDC00-\uDFFF]|\uD869[\uDC00-\uDED6\uDF00-\uDFFF]|\uD86D[\uDC00-\uDF34\uDF40-\uDFFF]|\uD86E[\uDC00-\uDC1D\uDC20-\uDFFF]|\uD873[\uDC00-\uDEA1]|\uD87E[\uDC00-\uDE1D]`

You may either use XRegExp (which is preferable since the library is constantly updated):

```js
var rx = new XRegExp("^[-\\w\\p{Hiragana}\\p{Katakana}\\p{Han}]+$");
console.log(XRegExp.test("werえ", rx));
console.log(XRegExp.test("werえ3", rx));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xregexp/3.2.0/xregexp-all.min.js"></script>
```

Or you may use those ranges to build a regex that you will have to support later:

```js
var pHiragana = "[\\u3041-\\u3096\\u309D-\\u309F]|\\uD82C\\uDC01|\\uD83C\\uDE00";
var pKatakana = "[\\u30A1-\\u30FA\\u30FD-\\u30FF\\u31F0-\\u31FF\\u32D0-\\u32FE\\u3300-\\u3357\\uFF66-\\uFF6F\\uFF71-\\uFF9D]|\\uD82C\\uDC00";
var pHan = "[\\u2E80-\\u2E99\\u2E9B-\\u2EF3\\u2F00-\\u2FD5\\u3005\\u3007\\u3021-\\u3029\\u3038-\\u303B\\u3400-\\u4DB5\\u4E00-\\u9FD5\\uF900-\\uFA6D\\uFA70-\\uFAD9]|[\\uD840-\\uD868\\uD86A-\\uD86C\\uD86F-\\uD872][\\uDC00-\\uDFFF]|\\uD869[\\uDC00-\\uDED6\\uDF00-\\uDFFF]|\\uD86D[\\uDC00-\\uDF34\\uDF40-\\uDFFF]|\\uD86E[\\uDC00-\\uDC1D\\uDC20-\\uDFFF]|\\uD873[\\uDC00-\\uDEA1]|\\uD87E[\\uDC00-\\uDE1D]";
var rx = new RegExp("^([\\w-]|" + pHiragana + "|" + pKatakana + "|" + pHan + ")+$");
console.log(rx.test("werえ"));
console.log(rx.test("werえ3"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example regex which would match Hiragana (unicode 3040-309F):
`/[a-zA-Z0-9_\u3040-\u309F]+/`
http://regexr.com/3frf9

You can alter this to add other dialects/languages. You may want to check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1801473/japanese-ascii-code) to see some of the other unicode values, or just look them up online elsewhere.